# Rule-based Territory assignments are being created when there are no territory rules

Tags: apex, territory-management

In an existing instance, we have a territory hierarchy with no rules, just manual assignments. Since the Summer '13 release we are seeing AccountShare records with RowCause of 'Territory' which indicates a rule-based assignment. Additionally, we are unable to delete these records

The following code produces an INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY error, even though all of the related records exist. While the error originates in a larger piece of code, I've extracted the following to reproduce the problem. The instance has Territory Management enabled and the code was working prior to the :Summer '13 update.

```
for (AccountShare s : [Select Id, UserOrGroupId, RowCause, IsDeleted From AccountShare Where AccountId = '001U0000006UFZE']) {
    if (s.RowCause == 'Territory') {
        System.debug(s.Id + ': ' + s.RowCause + ' - IsDelted: ' + s.IsDeleted);
        for (Group g : [Select RelatedId From Group Where Id = :s.UserOrGroupId]) {
            System.debug('Territory is ' + g.RelatedId);
            for (Territory t : [Select Name From Territory Where Id = :g.RelatedId]) {
                System.debug('Territory is ' + t.Name);
            }
        }
        try {
            delete s;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.debug('Deletion failed: ' + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

> USER_DEBUG [13]|DEBUG|Deletion failed: Delete failed. First exception
>   on row 0 with id 00rU0000004yvbMIAQ; first error:
>   INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, id does not exist: []

Answer (score 1):

Abrar, here (http://sforcecloud.blogspot.fr/2013/05/territory-management-in-apex.html) seems to assert that it is not possible to delete Territory AccountShares with APEX (DML).